# How the Stack object works with Value items

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, stack

Say I have this in my class

```
private static Stack<int> _cursorRefCounts = new Stack<int>();
```

when I call `_cursorRefCounts.Peek()` what gets returned?  Is it a reference or a value?

If I increment the value that gets returned then call Peek again, will be be one greater?

I seem to recall that what happens is that when it gets put in the Stack object the int gets boxed.  Then when it comes out it gets unboxed.  Does the unboxing make it a value item again?

If I want to increase the top item on the stack, how would I do that?  (Note: this is a multithreaded app.  I would like to just increment the top value without poping it off.  (Though I guess I could lock that section.))

Comment: It sounds like you've chosen the wrong collection class for the job. You shouldn't ever need to modify a value contained in a stack in place.

Comment: @Cody Gray -  why not?  If I make a simple object that contains a int property called RefCount then I can just say `++_cursorRefCounts.Peek().RefCount;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Peek` will return a value, so incrementing it will not modify the value on the stack.

To increment the top item, pop it off, increment, and push it back on.

Comment: Alas, if I pop the top item off, then another thread comes along and does the same thing, I could get a different result than if I just found a way to increment the top item.  I may have to make the top item a object so that I can update the int inside of it.

Comment: In a multi-thread environment you should use locks to make the increment operation atomic.

Comment: Couldn't I make my stack hold a simple object that contains a `public int RefCount { get; set; }` property then call `++_cursorRefCounts.Peek().RefCount;`?  Wouldn't that be thread safe too?

Comment: @Vaccano: it would not be thread safe if another thread was trying to increment the value at the same time. Say RefCount = 5. Two threads could read the Peek() result at the same time, see that value is 5, increment, and then you'll end up with 6 instead of 7. You will have to lock the increment section one way or another, so you might as well use a simpler Stack<int> implementation.

Comment: Hmmm, I thought Peek would return the reference to the item on the top of the list.  So, even if both threads peeked at the same time they would get the same reference.  Two calls to increment would result in the same int value in the same reference getting two increments.  (Unless the ++ operator is not thread safe?)  I admit I am not a Multi-threading genius.  So I may be WAY off on my assumptions.  Maybe I should just use lock to be on the safe side.

Comment: @vacca: the `++` operator is __not thread-safe__. As a rule of thumb, nothing in the language or library is thread-safe unless it is very explicitly documented to be safe.

Comment: @Vaccano Peek() only returns a reference for reference types. `int` is a value type, so a copy of the value is returned.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever type you define as the generic type for your `Stack` object, it's returned as that type. This is the magic of generics. Absolutely no boxing/unboxing is involved, you simply get an `int`.

Since `int` is a value type, you receive it as a value type, and not a reference to the value.

`Peek()` does not alter the stack. It simply tells you what's on top. To modify the value, as [Anna Lear says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627856/how-the-stack-object-works-with-value-items/4627873#4627873) you need to `Pop()` it first.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, `Peek<int>()` will return a value.

But even if it returned a boxed integer, or if the Stack was holding a mutable reference type, any operation on it would be  **not thread-safe**.

You should simply `lock` the thing :

```
lock(_cursorRefCounts)
{
    int v = _cursorRefCounts.Pop();
    _cursorRefCounts.Push(v+1);
}
```

Theoretically you should even use a helper object to lock on but in general this will do .